# How to draw 3-junction and 4-junction SQUIDs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, circuitikz

**UPDATE**

Thanks to John Kormylo I was able to draw a 4-junction SQUID using four components like:
[4-junction squid building block http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/squid4elem.png](http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/squid4elem.png)

The whole SQUID
[4-junction squid building block http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/squid4jcombined.png](http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/squid4jcombined.png)
is drawn using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}`

\newlength{\ResUp} \newlength{\ResDown}
\newlength{\ResLeft} \newlength{\ResRight}
\newlength{\ResLen} \newlength{\ResRadius}
\newlength{\whereamix} \newlength{\whereamiy}

\makeatletter
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}
\def\CircDirection{\pgf@circ@direction}

\pgf@circ@Rlen = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
\setlength{\ResLen}{\pgf@circ@Rlen}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% squid4 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ctikzset{bipoles/squid4/height/.initial=.6}
\ctikzset{bipoles/squid4/width/.initial=.6}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/squid4/height}}
{squid4}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/squid4/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/squid4/width}}
{
\pgfsetlinewidth{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
\pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\northeast}
\pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}
\pgfextractx{\ResLeft}{\southwest}
\pgfextracty{\ResDown}{\southwest}

\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1\ResLeft}{0\ResDown}}
\pgfpatharc{0}{-90}{1\ResLeft}%{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.8\ResUp}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0\ResLeft}{-1\ResDown}}
\pgfpatharc{-90}{-45}{1\ResLeft}

\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.35\ResLeft}{0.707\ResUp}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.064\ResLeft}{0.707\ResUp}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.707\ResLeft}{-0.35\ResDown}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.707\ResLeft}{1.064\ResUp}}
\pgfusepath{draw}   
}

\def\mysquidpath#1{\TikzBipolePath{squid4}{#1}}
\tikzset{squid4/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\mysquidpath, l=#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1] 
\draw (1,1) to [squid4, i^>=$I_1$] (-1,-1); 
\draw (-1,-1) to [squid4, i^<=$I_1$] (1,1); 
\draw (1,-1) to [squid4, i^<=$I_2$] (-1,1); 
\draw (-1,1) to [squid4, i^>=$I_2$] (1,-1); 
\end{circuitikz} \\
\end{document}
```

I still have a problem with the 3-junction SQUID. Any help would be appreciated.

---

I am using circuitikz to draw circuit diagrams that contain SQUID magnetometers. The package contains the **squid** symbol for a standard 2-junction SQUID. Using the code:
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1] 
\draw (0,1.8) to [squid, l^=$J_1$, i^>=$I_2$] (0,-0.5) 
      (0,1.8) to [squid, l_=$J_2$, i>^=$I_1$] (0,-0.5); 
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}`

I can draw the SQUID:

[2-junction SQUID http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/SQUID2JJ.png](http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/SQUID2JJ.png)

Now, I'd like to draw a 3-junction SQUID like this:

[3-junction SQUID http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/SQUID3JJ.png](http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/SQUID3JJ.png)

and a 4-junction SQUID like this:

[4-junction SQUID http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/SQUID4JJ.png](http://www.tau.ac.il/~suhuvale/SQUID4JJ.png)

How do I draw these symbols?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you want to learn how to do it, visit http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a 2-junction SQUID called `squid` in the `circuitikz`, the proposed solution modifies `squid` into `\squidthree` and `\squidfour` via `renewcommand` syntax to draw the symbols shown in the OP. Every symbol has internal input/output labels called `a1,b1,c1` and `a2,b2,c2,d2` counterclockwise so that they can be used for connections
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\squidthree}[1] 
{  % #1 = name , 
\draw[thick] (#1) circle (12pt);
\draw (#1) ++(0,12pt)    coordinate(a1);
\draw (#1) ++(-135:12pt) coordinate(b1);
\draw (#1) ++(-45:12pt)  coordinate(c1);
\draw[rotate=60,line width=1pt]   (#1)  
+(0,16pt)node[above left]{\tiny${J}_{1}$} -- +(0,8pt)  
+(-4pt,12pt) -- +(4pt,12pt);
\draw[rotate=-60,line width=1pt]  (#1)  
+(0,16pt)node[above right]{\tiny${J}_{3}$} -- +(0,8pt) 
+(-4pt,12pt) -- +(4pt,12pt);
\draw[rotate=0,line width=1pt]    (#1)  
+(0,-16pt)node[below]{\tiny${J}_{2}$} -- +(0,-8pt) 
+(-4pt,-12pt) -- +(4pt,-12pt);
}


\newcommand{\squidfour}[1] 
{  % #1 = name , 
\draw[thick] (#1) circle (12pt);
\draw (#1) ++(90:12pt)  coordinate(a2);
\draw (#1) ++(180:12pt) coordinate(b2);
\draw (#1) ++(270:12pt) coordinate(c2);
\draw (#1) ++(0:12pt)   coordinate(d2);
\draw[rotate=45,line width=1pt]   (#1)  
+(0,16pt)node[above left]  {\tiny${J}_{1}$} -- +(0,8pt)  
+(0,-16pt)node[below right]{\tiny${J}_{3}$} -- +(0,-8pt) 
+(-4pt,12pt) -- +(4pt,12pt)  
+(-4pt,-12pt) -- +(4pt,-12pt);
\draw[rotate=-45,line width=1pt]  (#1)  
+(0,16pt)node[above right]{\tiny${J}_{4}$} -- +(0,8pt)   
+(0,-16pt)node[below left]{\tiny${J}_{2}$} -- +(0,-8pt) 
+(-4pt,12pt)  -- +(4pt,12pt)  
+(-4pt,-12pt) -- +(4pt,-12pt);
}

\begin{document}  

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1] 

\node at (0,2) {2-junc SQUID};

\draw (0,1) to [squid, l^=$J_1$, i^>=$I_2$] (0,-1) 
         (0,1) to [squid, l_=$J_2$, i>^=$I_1$] (0,-1); 

\node at (3,2) {3-junc SQUID};

\path (3,1) to[squid,color=white,name=S1](3,-1);
\squidthree{S1} % at (2,0)
\draw (3,1.3) to[short,i=$I_1$]      (a1);
\draw (b1)    to[short,i_=$I_1-I_2$] (2,-1);
\draw (c1)    to[short,i=$I_2$]      (4,-1);

\node at (6,2){4-junc SQUID};

\path (6,1) to[squid,color=white,name=S2](6,-1);
\squidfour{S2}  % at (4,0)
\draw (6,1.3) to[short,i=$I_1$](a2);
\draw (4.7,0) to[short,i=$I_2$](b2);
\draw (c2)    to[short,i=$I_1$](6,-1.3);
\draw (d2)    to[short,i=$I_2$](7.3,0);

\end{circuitikz} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Jesse. It is almost what I meant. To use these symbols the X's should be rotated by 45 degrees.

Comment: @vilka `\newcommand{\squidfour}[1] {
\draw[thick] (#1) circle (12pt);
\draw (#1) ++(90:12pt)  coordinate(a2);
\draw (#1) ++(180:12pt) coordinate(b2);
\draw (#1) ++(270:12pt) coordinate(c2);
\draw (#1) ++(0:12pt)   coordinate(d2);
\draw[line width=1pt]   (#1)  
+(8pt,14pt)node[right]  {\tiny${J}_{4}$} -- +(8pt,4pt)
+(-8pt,-14pt)node[left]{\tiny${J}_{2}$} -- +(-8pt,-4pt)
+(13pt,9pt) -- +(3pt,9pt) 
+(-13pt,-9pt) -- +(-3pt,-9pt);`

Comment: and the second part for the same macro `\draw[line width=1pt]  (#1)  
+(-8pt,14pt)node[left]{\tiny${J}_{1}$} -- +(-8pt,4pt)   
+(8pt,-14pt)node[right]{\tiny${J}_{3}$} -- +(8pt,-4pt)
+(13pt,-9pt)  -- +(3pt,-9pt)  
+(-13pt,9pt) -- +(-3pt,9pt);
}`